# How to resolve the linker error in C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors, pjsip

I have to compile `PJSIP` in `CPP` compiler. Because I am integrating an API with `PJSIP`. It is in `CPP`. So I have to use `g++` instead of `gcc`. But now I didn't integrate any other API.

But I am getting linker error in `CPP` compiler. If it is `C` compiler, it is working fine.

**Error:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm:
  "_crypto_alloc", referenced from:
      srtp_stream_clone(srtp_stream_ctx_t const*, unsigned int, srtp_stream_ctx_t**)in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
      srtp_stream_alloc(srtp_stream_ctx_t**, srtp_policy_t const*) in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
      _srtp_create in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
  "_aes_icm_context_init", referenced from:
      srtp_kdf_init(srtp_kdf_t*, unsigned char const*)in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
  "_crypto_kernel_load_debug_module", referenced from:
      _srtp_init in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
  "_rdbx_init", referenced from:
      srtp_stream_init(srtp_stream_ctx_t*, srtp_policy_t const*) in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
      srtp_stream_clone(srtp_stream_ctx_t const*, unsigned int, srtp_stream_ctx_t**)in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
  "_key_limit_clone", referenced from:
      srtp_stream_clone(srtp_stream_ctx_t const*, unsigned int, srtp_stream_ctx_t**)in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
  "_auth_get_tag_length", referenced from:
      _srtp_unprotect_rtcp in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
      _srtp_protect_rtcp in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
      _srtp_unprotect in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
      _srtp_protect in libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a(srtp.o)
...
...
```

Actually I didn't change anything in `makefile`.

**NOTE:**
In `srtp.c` file, already included `alloc.h` file. I commended it and compiled it. I got the same linker error only. I am thinking in two ways. But I am not sure with this.
1. It is not linking with `.o` files
2. It is not taking the header files. (I am not clear with this.)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Btw, `CPP` means C preprocessor. `C++` means C plus plus.

Comment: Is it clear to you the difference between "compiling" and "linking" and that C++ cannot compile C and C cannot compile C++ but that C++ can export to C if a linker in invoked separately and after?

Comment: We can compile C code with C++ compiler and C++ code with C compiler. But the thing is; If you use namespace and etc in you c++ code, you can not compile the c++ code with C compiler.

Comment: @jfalexvijay: That's largely nonsense. You can't compile all C code with a C++ compiler and you certainly can't compile all C++ code with a C compiler. There are *some* programs that are both C and C++, but even with those you can get linking issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't compile C source code with a C++ compiler. Just compile it with a C compiler and link it into your C++ program using a C++ linker.
2. Declare all C symbols in an `extern "C"` block; either wrap your `#include` directives in such a block, or put it in the headers themselves. (Check whether there's not such a block in the headers already.)

See also [How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) in the C++ FAQ.

Comment: Regarding `1.`: you may like to compile C code with a C++ compiler if C code calls back into C++ and C++ code throws an exception. That doesn't make C code safe against exceptions, however, that exception at least can be propagated without crashing the application.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Compiling C code as-is with a C++ compiler might invoke very subtle semantic differences between the languages. I've been bit by them and I wouldn't recommend it to anyone.

Comment: Actually I am going to call CPP function from C file. Not C function from CPP. That is the problem.

Comment: Then you need to declare your C++ functions as `extern "C"`.

Comment: Now I didn't include any C++ files. I am compiling the C code in C++ compiler. If it is succeeded, then I will include the c++ files into C file.

Comment: @jfalexvijay: you *shouldn't* compile C code with a C++ compiler. You should link it with a C++ linker if you want interop.

Answer (score 2):

When `C` symbols become undefined in a `C++` program it means that their declarations are not marked as `extern "C"`.

The standard way to handle it is to wrap `C` headers with:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// C declarations here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I did the same thing. But I am getting the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's linker error in your pjsip project. Are you using xcode or anyother IDE to develop this project?

This error is because, the above files are not linked to your project successfully.

Add this below missing library file into your project.

=>>libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a

Follow the below link to link your library file into your project.

SOURCE: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib.asp